# group mysql results by id for looping

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a table that has flight data in mysql. Im writing a php code that will group and display the data in groups using codeigniter 3

```
 journey_id     air_id  FlightDuration  out_or_in   flightduration2
    1           1           20hr 5min   outbound    1205
    2           1           20hr 5min   outbound    1300
    3           1           17hr 55min  inbound     2258
    4           1           17hr 55min  inbound     1075
    5           2           31hr 40min  outbound    1970
    6           2           31hr 40min  outbound    1900
    7           2           17hr 55min  inbound     2223
    8           2           17hr 55min  inbound     1987
    9           3           10hr 45min  outbound    645
    10          3           11hr 25min  inbound     685
```

im using a `$this->db->get()` to retrieve the data and i can easily loop through. but since each row is in array im finding it difficult to group them. i cannot use the mysql group coz i need each row.

for an example i want to display the items as below

```
air_id - 1
20hr 5min   outbound    1205
20hr 5min   outbound    1300
17hr 55min  inbound     2258
17hr 55min  inbound     1075

air_id - 2
31hr 40min  outbound    1970
31hr 40min  outbound    1900
17hr 55min  inbound     2223
17hr 55min  inbound     1987

air_id - 3
10hr 45min  outbound    645
11hr 25min  inbound     685
```

what would be the best way to group the result by the `air_id` so i can iterate through

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Fetch the data from the database:

   ```
   $this->db->select('journey_id, air_id, FlightDuration, out_or_in, flightduration2');
    $this->db->from('your_table_name'); // Replace 'your_table_name' with the actual table name
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $data = $query->result_array();
   ```
2. Create an empty array to hold the grouped data:

   ```
    $grouped_data = array();
   ```
3. Iterate through the fetched data and group it by air_id:

   ```
   foreach ($data as $row) {

       $air_id = $row['air_id'];

       // Check if the air_id already exists in the grouped_data array
       if (!isset($grouped_data[$air_id])) {
           // If not, initialize an empty array for this air_id
           $grouped_data[$air_id] = array();
       }

       // Add the current row to the group for this air_id
       $grouped_data[$air_id][] = $row;
   }
   ```
4. Now, you have the data grouped by air_id in the $grouped_data array. You can iterate through this array to display the data as you specified:

   ```
   foreach ($grouped_data as $air_id => $group) {
       echo "air_id - $air_id<br>";

       foreach ($group as $row) {
           echo $row['FlightDuration'] . ' ' . $row['out_or_in'] . ' ' . $row['flightduration2'] . '<br>';
       }

       echo "<br>";
   }
   ```

This code will loop through the grouped data and display it as you described, with each group of flight data under the corresponding air_id.